# Autofit specific cells row using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, row, height, auto

could someone give me vba code for 
Autofitting specific cell's row using VBA when the sheet is protected 
obviously the specific cell that I am trying to autofit which j32 is not locked

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To autofit a cell's row do this:

```vb
Range("A1").EntireRow.Autofit
```